# run clean verify -Denv=dev error

Tags: angular, maven, docker, glassfish

Good day, when I run the command

```
clean verify -Denv=dev
```

I have this error

> :Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (install npm) on project monitopsy-web: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "npm"

can you help please

Comment: Toy need to install npm

Comment: I am a beginner and I understood that he can not execute the npm on the web project. can you tell me how i can configure this in the pom? what is the plugin that I have to add for example?

Comment: Can you run npm -v on the command line ? If not install npm at https://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your Maven build use the Maven Exec Plugin and tries to run the `npm` command. However, the environment on which you are trying to run your build does not have `npm` installed or cannot access it.

You should make sure `npm` is installed on the environment you are running your build. Take a look here: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/85484771375/how-to-install-npm